# Using a custom font in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, seaborn

I have a custom .ttf file and I am trying to use it in a seaborn plot. Here's what I have so far:

```py
from matplotlib import font_manager
path = "path/to/Roboto-Black.ttf"
fm = font_manager.FontManager()
fm.addfont(path)

prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
sns.set(font=prop.get_name())
```

But this doesn't work, I simply get the warning:

```
findfont: Font family 'Roboto' not found.
```

I am using the latest matplotlib version 3.6.1. Also, I cannot install any fonts in the system as I don't have sudo access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default FontManager instance that needs to be used rather than creating a new instance:

```py
from matplotlib.font_manager import fontManager, FontProperties

path = "path/to/Roboto-Black.ttf"
fontManager.addfont(path)

prop = FontProperties(fname=path)
sns.set(font=prop.get_name())
```

See [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.0/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py#L1628) for more details.